# Can't redirect request from IP to domain name (nginx). Got "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, ip

I have a server that runs on Nginx (ubuntu 16). I also have a domain name that redirects to the IP of this server. Of course, I want to show the user a domain name in the address bar, not IP (as it is now). To do this, I changed the site configuration settings in the `/etc/nginx/sites-aviable` folder to the following: (the project is written in symfony, location is mostly from docks on it)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name **.***.***.***; #My server ip
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/web;
    index app.php app_dev.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
        proxy_buffer_size          128k;
        proxy_buffers              4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;

    }
    # DEV
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
    # Phpmyadmin Configurations
        location /phpmyadmin {
            root /usr/share/;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                root /usr/share/;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                #fastcgi_param HTTPS on; # <-- add this line
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
       location ~*^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))${
                root /usr/share/;
       }
    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {
        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

As a result, now the user sees the domain name in the address bar, but it does not bring joy - the browsers write `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` and do not show the content.

As I understand, in some place there is a recursive redirect. In addition to `*/nginx/sites-aviable/example.com` there are no other configs in this folder (default file is fully commented out).

Could it be that the server receiving a request to the address `**.***.***.***:80` redirect it to `example.com`, and the domain services, catching the request, will redirect to `**.***.***.***:80`, and so on a loop?

How then to be? Or is the problem somewhere in local configurations?

UPD It is the contents of the access.log file after the attempt to open the site once: 
(the line is repeated 9 times, **.** . **. *** - IP of my server)

```
**. ***. ***. *** - - [03/Oct/2017: 11: 59: 07 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv: 54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

UPD 2
I try `curl -L -I http://mysite`
Result of curl:

```
'HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 09:49:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://**.***.***.***  //(my server IP)

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 09:49:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://example.com //(my cite)

....
// some repeats this
....

curl: (52) Empty reply from server'
```

Redirect 301 is described in my configuration.
Why there is a redirect 302 - I do not know. Is this the result of DNS services?

Comment: If you have just made this change, you will need to clear the browser cache, otherwise it will remember the previous redirect, which will produce a loop.

Comment: Yes, I already cleared the cache, it did not help. Also, while working with configs, I changed 301 to 302, as far as I know, browsers can't cached 302.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to ensure that `nginx` is reading your configuration without errors. Look at the access log to ensure that your server is responsible for the entire redirection cycle. Check your PHP application to ensure that the IP address is not hardwired into code or a database.

Comment: I looked at nginx-T, I did not see any problems in the configuration. Here is the contents of the access.log file after the attempt to open the site once: (the line is repeated 9 times, **. ***. ***. *** - IP of my server) `**. ***. ***. *** - - [03 / Oct / 2017: 11: 59: 07 +0300] "GET / HTTP / 1.1" 301 194 "-" "Mozilla / 5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv: 54.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 54.0 "` Can we say something on this log?

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug using **curl**:

For example:

```
curl -L -I http://yoursite
```

the option `-L` will follow redirects and the `-I` will only show the headers.

In the output search for `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` and the `Location: htt.....`

Also try to change your conf to either use http or https in many cases is where the loop happends:

```
return 301 $scheme://
```

to

```
return 301 https://
```

Comment: I could not attach the result to the commentary, and edited the question, adding there the results of the curl query in "UPD"

Answer (score 0):

The error was not on the side of my server or the nginx configuration, I did not correctly configure DNS when I had a domain name. Instead of creating an A-record, I set a redirect to the IP of my server